# Creating a popover triggers a warning... $tooltip is now deprecated. Use $uibTooltip instead

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a popover on the anchor tag hover. Using the below code:
angular: 1.4.2
ui-bootstrap :0.14.2

```html
<div class="row" ng-repeat="endorsement in endorsements| filter: {category:categorySelected}">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="{{endorsement.number+endorsement.category}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="endorsement.selected" class="border-horizontal" />
    <label for="{{endorsement.number+endorsement.category}}">{{endorsement.category}}</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <label popover="{{endorsement.desc}}" popover-trigger="'mouseenter'" popover-placement="top" popover-class="fg-blue" popover-title="{{endorsement.title}}"> {{endorsement.title}} </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using **ui-bootstrap**. Change `popover` to `uib-popover` (and other components accordingly)